# AFNetworking 2.0: Subclassing AFHTTPSessionManager for TDD causing error in AFURLRequestSerialization init

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I've subclassed `AFHTTPSessionManager` in order to make a mock out of it to use while testing. However, I keep running into a BAD_ACCESS error in `AFURLRequestSerialization`'s `init` method - only with the mock. Here's the setup:

Testing class:

```
@interface PLBookCommunicatorTests : XCTestCase
@end

@implementation PLBookCommunicatorTests
{
    MockAFHTTPSessionManager *httpSessionManager;
    HKCommunicator *communicator;
}

- (void)setUp
{
     [super setUp];

     httpSessionManager = [[MockAFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://base.url"]];

     communicator = [[HKCommunicator alloc] initWithHttpSessionManager:httpSessionManager];
}
```

MockAFHTTPSessionMannager.h

```
#import "AFHTTPSessionManager.h"

@interface MockAFHTTPSessionManager : AFHTTPSessionManager

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL successful;

@end
```

MockAFHTTPSessionManager.m

```
import <AFNetworking.h>
#import "MockAFHTTPSessionManager.h"

@implementation MockAFHTTPSessionManager

- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)GET:(NSString *)URLString parameters:(id)parameters success:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *, id))success failure:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *, NSError *))failure
{
    if(self.successful)
    {
        success(nil, nil);
    }
    else
    {
        failure(nil, nil);
    }

    return nil;
}

@end
```

I run into an error in this portion of `AFURLRequestSerialization`'s init method:

```
self.mutableObservedChangedKeyPaths = [NSMutableSet set];
for (NSString *keyPath in AFHTTPRequestSerializerObservedKeyPaths()) {
    if ([self respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(keyPath)]) {
        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:keyPath    options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew     context:AFHTTPRequestSerializerObserverContext];
    }
}
```

Specifically, at the `[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:keyPath    options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew     context:AFHTTPRequestSerializerObserverContext];` line. It catches on the very first run of that `for` loop

I'm not understanding why that line catches only in my mock. Is there something I'm missing while subclassing `AFHTTPSessionManager`? Perhaps something to do with the `addObserver` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed shortly after in release 2.5.1 of AFNetworking: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/releases/tag/2.5.1